# android Alexa auto find downloaded ndk path

Tags: android, android-ndk, alexa-skills-kit

This is the setup-android-toolchin.sh file `

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

THISDIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
source ${THISDIR}/common.sh

# Default external values
: ${NDK_PACKAGE:="android-ndk-r16b"}
: ${NDK_SHA1SUM:="42aa43aae89a50d1c66c3f9fdecd676936da6128"}

# Extra options
ANDROID_ABI=${1}
API_LEVEL=${2}

#
# Param checks
#

if [ -z ${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN} ]; then
    error "ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN is not set"
fi

if [ -z ${ANDROID_ABI} ] || [ -z ${API_LEVEL} ]; then
    error "Please specify ABI/API"
fi

# Android toolchain path
ANDROID_NDK="${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN}/ndk"
ANDROID_SDK="${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN}/sdk"

# Standard Android path
ANDROID_NDK_HOME="${ANDROID_NDK}/ndk-bundle/${NDK_PACKAGE}"

# OS detection
if [ $(uname) = "Darwin" ]; then
    HOST="darwin"
else
    HOST="linux"
fi

install() {
    filename=${1}
    checksum=${2}
    dest=${3}
    tmpdir=${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN}
    tmpfile=${tmpdir}/${filename}

    if [ -e ${tmpfile} ] && [ ! "$(sha1sum ${tmpfile})" = "${checksum}" ]; then
        warn "SHA1 checksum is wrong, re-download NDK package..."
        rm ${tmpfile}
    fi
    if [ ! -e ${dest} ]; then
        note "Downloading file ${filename}"
        wget --no-check-certificate https://dl.google.com/android/repository/${filename} -P ${tmpdir}
        sha1sum ${tmpfile}
    fi
    mkdir -p ${dest}
    pushd ${dest}
    unzip -q ${tmpfile}
    popd
}

generate_toolchain() {
    case ${ANDROID_ABI} in
        x86)
            ARCH="x86"
            ;;
        x86_64)
            ARCH="x86_64"
            ;;
        armeabi-v7a)
            ARCH="arm"
            ;;
        arm64-v8a)
            ARCH="arm64"
            ;;
        *)
            error "Unknown ABI: ${ANDROID_ABI}"
    esac

    TOOLCHAIN="${ANDROID_NDK}/toolchains/${NDK_PACKAGE}/toolchain-${ANDROID_ABI}/android-${API_LEVEL}"

    if [ ! -d ${TOOLCHAIN} ]; then
        note "Generating Standalone Toolchain..."

        ${ANDROID_NDK}/ndk-bundle/${NDK_PACKAGE}/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py \
        --arch="${ARCH}" \
        --api="${API_LEVEL}" \
        --stl="libc++" \
        --force \
        --install-dir="${TOOLCHAIN}"
    fi
}

note "Checking Android toolchain installation (${ANDROID_ABI}/${API_LEVEL})..."

if [ ! -d ${ANDROID_NDK_HOME} ]; then
    note "Installing NDK (${NDK_PACKAGE})..."
    install ${NDK_PACKAGE}-${HOST}-x86_64.zip ${NDK_SHA1SUM} ${ANDROID_NDK}/ndk-bundle
fi
if [ ! -d ${ANDROID_SDK} ]; then
    note "Installing SDK Tools..."
    install sdk-tools-${HOST}-3859397.zip "7eab0ada7ff28487e1b340cc3d866e70bcb4286e" ${ANDROID_SDK}
fi

generate_toolchain
```

`. After running the script it downloaded the NDK in /workdir/android. I am not getting where it has downloaded the NDK as I am not able to find it through finder(Mac OS High Sierra). Can anyone tell the path to where I can find the NDK. Using search option is not helping me.